# Azure Service Plan - Scale out charges

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Do i need to pay twice the monthly charges (56$/month) if I "scale out" my basic service plan to 2 instances ? Or price is inclusive up to 3 instances ?

Comment: Please check if this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40579661/how-scale-out-work-in-azure-app-services) answers your question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll be charged per instance when you scale out. So two instances will be $112/month, and three will be $168/month.

Comment: That makes sense but is it even officially documented somewhere?!

Comment: Yep, see the pricing calculator below that Tom Sun posted.

Answer (score 7):

As Rob Reagan mentioned  that it will be charged per instance. We can get the price via  azure [pricing calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?service=app-service). More details please refer to the screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are not going to use the 3 capabilities full time, program the horizontal scale of your service to use at least 1 to 3 instances when you reach a certain parameter you can choose. This way you will pay for the additional machines only for as long as they are needed.