# understand functions apps servers number in connected application insight

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have one Application Service Plan. Premium Tier. 3 Functions Apps. 3 application insights.
For ASP settings for every function app I have this settings
[image]

what does mean this number of servers when I open stream in application insights?
[image]

when I dont have any jobs to execute in any functions I see that number of servers is 2 for every function app. If some function does some jobs I see more servers allocated for this function. As I understand when no jobs, 2 servers means 1 mandatory instance  + 1 always ready.As as  I see the same servers allocated for all 3 functions apps. Does it means that "server" it is not the same as "function app" object?
[image]

Comment: Here the system is described by Microsoft = https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-premium-plan?tabs=portal#always-ready-instances

Comment: Also checkout this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40579661/how-does-scaling-out-work-in-azure-app-services Its the same question

Answer (score 2):

You are right. Since all your function apps are using the same App Service plan, they will share the server instances pool. As you have understood, there will be 2 active servers if your function app was in active use with some workload. If the load increases, Azure would assign work to the pre-warmed instance and create 1 more 'Always ready' instance. Unless you have set the `Maximum burst` limit for the App Service Plan, or the `Max scale out limit` for any of the Function app, Azure will keep adding VM instances to the server pool as workload increases.